# pandas drop rows that share similar value in other column

Tags: python

I have DataFrame `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["a","b","c","d","e"], 'col2': [1,3,3,2,6]})` that looks like

**Input:**

```
 col1 col2
0   a   1
1   b   3
2   c   3
3   d   2
4   e   6
```

I would like to remove rows from "col1" that share a common value in "col2". The expected output would look something like...

**Output:**

```
 col1 col2
0   a   1
3   d   2
4   e   6
```

What would be the process of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using this short code should do the trick

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col2'], keep=False)
```

**Explanation**

we use `drop_duplicates` to (ovbiously) drop the duplicates, and we set the column(s) we want to drop from to be `col2` as you requested, In order to drop all occurences (and not keep the first occurence of each duplicate for example) we use `keep=False`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["a","b","c","d","e"], 'col2': [1,3,3,2,6]})

c = Counter(df['col2'])
ls = [k for k,v in c.items() if v==1]

_fltr = df['col2'].isin(ls)

df.loc[_fltr,:]
```